# c++ between three numbers sum two highers without loops and arrays

Tags: c++, algorithm

How to write c++ program that will let user enters three numbers, and find between that three ***2 higest*** and write smth like : 5,3,4 sum of 5 and 4 is 9!

I tried allready, but I get too many if elses and it looks really bad, and even not working well in all cases :/

```
#include <iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    float n1, n2, n3;
cout << "Enter three numbers: ";
    cin >> n1 >> n2 >> n3;

    if(n1 >= n2 && n1 >= n3)
    {
        if(n2>=n1 && n2>=3)
            cout << "Sum of 2 highest between this three numbers is: "  << cout<<n1+n2;
    }

    if(n1 >= n2 && n1 >= n3)
    {
        if(n3>=n1 && n3>=n2)
            cout << "Sum of 2 highest between this three numbers is: "  << cout<<n1+n3;
    }

    if(n2 >= n1 && n2 >= n3)
    {
        if(n3 >= n1 && n3 >= n2) {
            cout << "Sum of 2 highest between this three numbers is: " << cout<<n3+n2;
        }
    }

    if(n3 >= n1 && n3 >= n2)
    {
        if(n2 >= n1) {
            cout << "Sum of 2 highest between this three numbers is: "  << cout<<n3+n2;
        }
    }

    if(n3 >= n1 && n3 >= n2)
    {
        if(n1>= n2) {
            cout << "Sum of 2 highest between this three numbers is: "  << cout<<n3+n1;
        }
    }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know if it will help, but if `n1 > n2 && n2 > n3` then that implies that `n1 > n3` as well.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude come on man lets find 2 highest number here :D

Comment: some lambda with stable_sort could be handy, do you accept use of vectors?

Comment: Well if `n1 > n2 && n2 > n3` the two highest are `n1` and `n2`. Rotate the variables used in the expression one step and you can easily get all the variants. Another way to shorter the code down is to use two variables for the max numbers, and only sum them and print the result at the end.

Comment: *I tried allready, but I get too many if elses and it looks really bad, and even not working well in all cases* -- What did you expect?  This is why arrays and loops are used.

Comment: Can you please clarify the question? Do you want to find the larges 2 numbers as well, or just their sum?

Answer (score 2):

Find the minimum first,

```
double min = std::min(n1, std:min(n2, n3)); // or std::min({n1, n2, n3})
```

then eliminate it

```
if(min == n1)
{ 
    std::cout << n2 << ' ' << n3 << ' ' << n2 + n3;
}
else if(min == n2) 
{ 
    std::cout << n1 << ' ' << n3 << ' ' << n1 + n3;
}
else 
{ 
    std::cout << n1 << ' ' << n2 << ' ' << n1 + n2;
}
```

[<kbd>Live example</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a68d31e50e949860)

Of course if you're really picky you can replace the call to [`std::min`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) by

```
double min = n1;
if(n2 < min)
    min = n2;
if(n3 < min)
    min = n3;
```

Another solution is to just do the min finding and elimination in a single step, like

```
if(n1 < n2 && n1 < n3) // min is n1
{
    std::cout << n2 << ' ' << n3 << ' ' << n2 + n3;
}
else if(n2 < n1 && n2 < n3) // min is n2
{
    std::cout << n1 << ' ' << n3 << ' ' << n1 + n3;
}
else // min is n3
{
    std::cout << n1 << ' ' << n2 << ' ' << n1 + n2;
}
```

In terms of complexity, both solutions are identical, i.e. require 4 comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
max = (n1>n2) ? ( (n1>n3) ? n1 : n3) : ((n2>n3) ? n2 : n3);
second = (n1==max) ? ( (n2>n3) ? n2 : n3) : ((n2==max) ? ((n1>n3) ? n1 : n3) : ((n2>n1)? n2 : n1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to do a few checks to get the desired result.

```
int n1 = 0,n2 = 0,n3 = 0;
cin>>n1>>n2>>n3;

int highest = 0;
int second_highest = 0;

if(n1 > n2)
{
    if(n1 > n3)
    {
        highest = n1;
        if(n3 > n2)
        {
            second_highest = n3;
        }
        else
        {
            second_highest = n2;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        highest = n3;
        second_highest = n1;
    }
}
else if(n2 > n3) // if the first if is false it means that the n2 is highest or second highest
{
    highest = n2;
    if(n1 > n3)
    {
        second_highest = n1;
    }
    else
    {
        second_highest = n3;
    }
}
else
{
    highest = n3;
    second_highest = n2;
}

cout << "Highest: " << highest << "\nSecond highest: " << second_highest;
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach to answer the question as asked would be

```
  cout << "Sum of 2 highest between this three numbers is: ";
  cout << (long long) n1 + n2 + n3 - std::min(n1, std::min(n2, n3));
```

or (C++11)

```
  cout << "Sum of 2 highest between this three numbers is: ";
  cout << (long long) n1 + n2 + n3 - std::min({n1, n2, n3});
```

The `(long long)` conversion forces all values being added or subtracted to be promoted before the operation, to avoid overflow if `int` supports a smaller range of values than a `long long`.

Of course, this does embed a fixed assumption of three values being worked with.

Comment: That's neat, but you also need to find the largest 2 numbers (at least that's what OP asks in his example); although was not stated in the title

Comment: That was not stated in the question.

Comment: *and find between that three 2 higest and write smth like : 5,3,4 sum of 5 and 4 is 9!* Bit ambiguous, but considering the code OP wrote probably he wants the numbers as well

Comment: Given that the OP did not attempt to print out the two largest values, I drew a different conclusion.

Comment: Yeah I see now that OP was not attempting to print them... If he just wants the sum, of course this is the way to go!

Comment: That's also why the first `cout` statement in both examples uses the same incorrect wording in the string literal as the OP had  ;)